# kendo MVVM checkbox unbinds automatically when disabling another checkbox

Tags: jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

The model is Array of Objects. Below is my OnClick event code to check uncheck other checkbox based on PNR property. if same PNR checkbox stays 'ENABLED' else 'DISABLED'. I am using Kendo MVVM.

```
  HTML code:
<td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected ,events: {click: OnTicketTstCheck},disabled: IsDisabled" /> </td>

script code:


    function OnTicketTSTCheckProcess(e) {
                debugger;
                if ($(e.target).prop("checked") == true) {

                    var element = e.target;
                    var PNR = e.target.kendoBindingTarget.source.Pnr;
                    $.each(TicketviewModel.TicketVMList,
                        function(i, v) {
                            debugger;
                            if (v.Pnr == PNR) {
                                v.set("IsDisabled", false);
                            } else {
                                v.set("IsDisabled", true);       
                            }
                        });

                } 
                else {
                    var anyChecked = false;
                    var PNR = $(e.target).closest(".TicketItem").find(".pnr").text();
                    $.each(TicketviewModel.TicketVMList,
                        function(i, v) {
                            debugger;
                            if (v.IsSelected == true) {
                                anyChecked = true;
                            }
                        });


                    if (anyChecked == false) {
                        $.each(TicketviewModel.TicketVMList,
                            function(i, v) {
                                debugger;
                                v.set("IsDisabled", false);
                            });
                    }

                }
            }
```

when below line gets executed 
v.set("IsDisabled", true);
  the selected checkbox gets deselected